# Angular Material dialog in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular

In my Angular app i have a module called `MaterialModule` that includes the following content:

```
imports: [
  MatDialogModule,
  ...
],
exports: [
  MatDialogModule,
  ...
]
```

It is exported in a module called `SharedModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

I would like to show a dialog from one of my lazy loaded components, so in my lazy loaded module i import this `SharedModule` and add the dialog component as an entry component:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyLazyLoadedComponent,
    MyDialogComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [MyDialogComponent]
})
export class MyLazyLoadedModule { }
```

But whenever i try to open the dialog from `MyLazyLoadedComponent`, i get the following error message:

> No component factory found for MyDialogComponent. Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents?

Opening dialogs from components that are not lazy loaded works fine.

I'd really appreciate any advice on what could be wrong with my configuration.

Comment: You are trying to open dialog in another module so that module needs the entry component. you need to export it in sharedmodule and put in entrycomponent of the module where you are opening the dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing components into the entryComponents portion of the NgModule declaration will allow Angular to compile those components into component factories and therefore allow the component resolver to add them to the internal map used for component resolution.
You need to import `MatDialogModule` directly in `MyLazyLoadedModule`.

Angular v6+: if you are using the `MatDialog` service inside another injectable service and is using the `{ providedIn: 'root' }` option for that service, you'll need to instead provide that service in the providers array of the module where your dialog components are declared.

Comment: I've added `MatDialogModule` to the `imports` array of `MyLazyLoadedModule`. The result is the same.

Comment: are you using the MatDialog service inside another injectable service and is using the { providedIn: 'root' } ?

Comment: Yes, i have a `DialogService` with `providedIn: 'root'`. That's what i'm using to show dialogs across my application.

Comment: so you'll need to instead provide that service in the providers array of the module where your dialog components are declared.

Comment: If I provide the service in each module the dialog components are declared then I would have multiple instances of the same service in each module. Is there a way to let the service be singleton?